# Resolving 'Pardon the Interruption' Error on Windows After Building Chromium from Source

Tags: c++, google-chrome, chromium, chromium-os

Why am I encountering a 'Pardon the interruption error' when trying to access certain websites after building Chromium from source on a Windows machine? I've successfully built Chromium on Linux where the websites work fine, but on Windows, I'm facing this issue. I've already checked the discussion on the Chromium-dev Google Group (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev/c/FZv-893ZvCo/m/n_nzMPTLAQAJ), where it was suggested that Chromium isn't commonly used on Windows, potentially leading to blocking.

However, I've noticed that other Chromium-based browsers function well on Windows. Are there any specific files in the Chromium source that I should override or implement to resolve this blocking issue? I'm looking for guidance on how to modify the Chromium source code to make it work seamlessly on Windows, allowing me to access websites without encountering this block.

I tried changing the user-agent string as suggested in the forum to pretend it as Linux and also tried to change some navigator properties to make it work. But non of that has worked so far.

Comment: It should work w/o any issues on Windows. We have our own Chromium fork that our users have been using since so many years, never noticed or heard of that issue till now. You must have made some changes which is causing that issue

Comment: @Asesh I built the chromium following this documentation. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md. I have not made any changes to the code. Is there any specific configuration I need to do? Also, I noticed the website is blocking Chromium only on Windows. While using Chromium on Ubuntu it is working fine.